# Table does offscreen latex

Tags: tables, width

For some reason, as I am trying to increase and add columns, it goes offscreen. Why does this happen exactly:
**Latex:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\textheight = 220mm
\textwidth = 150mm
\topmargin = 10mm
\oddsidemargin = 5.0mm
\evensidemargin = 5.0mm
\unitlength = 1mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}%
\small
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison}\label{tab:comparison}
        \begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}| }
        \hline
        OS & \hfil Secure & \hfil Fast & \hfil Beautiful & \hfil Smart & \hfil Error free \\ \hline
        Windows & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \\ \hline
        MAC OSX & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \\ \hline
        Linux & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: width of your table is 20cm, declared text width is 15 cm , so it cannot fit in text area. You may consider to change column types to `l` or `c` and by this force that column widths will be adopt to width of cells contents.

Comment: @Zarko, How would I do this?

Comment: @Zarko, doesn't work. I am sorry.

Comment: why are you forcing the columns to be so wide? `p{5cm}` for the first column seems excessive for the text you show, just use `l` so the column is the width of its content

Comment: It works, for sure! See my answer. However, your question is not very clear about desired table layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more issues with your MWE (Minimal working example):

- document layout is not consistent. I suggest to use `geometry` package for defining it
- because you load `tabularray` package I would use it for write your table:
- MWE with only to your problem related packages is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=5mm, vmargin={10mm,67mm}]{geometry} % new

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison}\label{tab:comparison}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                     colspec={l *{5}{c}},
                     } 
    OS      & Secure     & Fast       & Beautiful  & Smart  & Error free    \\
    Windows & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &        &               \\
    MAC OSX & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &        &               \\  
    Linux   & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &        &               \\
        \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines are borders of page)

Also seven columns can be fit in text area:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=5mm, vmargin={10mm,67mm}]{geometry} % new

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison}\label{tab:comparison}
        \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                     colspec={l *{7}{X[c,m]}},
                     } 
    OS      & Secure     & Fast       & Beautiful  & Smart  & Error free &  &   \\
    Windows & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &        &            &  &   \\
    MAC OSX & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &        &            &  &   \\  
    Linux   & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark &        &            &  &   \\
        \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko, if I add, 7 columns, `colspec={l *{7}{c}}` it goes offscreen.

Comment: @AlbinM, it is very difficult to put elephant into lady suitcase ... Regarding your comment your question is duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options.

Comment: Zarko, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @AlbinM, you are welcome!